# backstage plugin-stack-overflow set up and demo

Tags: stackexchange-api, backstage

[pick of the error we are getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofFVI.png)

so I recently trying to up skill myself in the backstage plug-in environments. but keep running into problems with setting up and using some of the plugins mainly the stackoverflow one  (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@backstage/plugin-stack-overflow ). I've been to successfully been able to install the plug into backstage and use some of the functionality provided mainly the templates that provides for UI design. however whenever I try to use a plugin that calls the stackoverflow APIs I'm giving the error that I get on this attached screenshot.  I can see on the npm page for this plugin that I need to configure the base URL in my app but I'm unsure about where to put this configuration I have tried attaching it to the yaml file in every place I can possibly think but I've been unsuccessful. if anyone has any advice about anything to do with plugins or this particular problem their help would be greatly appreciated

1.
Adding the following config to multiple files:

stackoverflow:
baseUrl: https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2

2.
Looked into the raw source code of the package and tried to call components from inside such as creating new class instances.
3.
Asking chat bots for help on configuration with none of them being able to directly tell me what file I need to modify
4.
Created a  new page to test out code

5.
looked at the backstage storybook for example code and tried to use their example to create a functioning demo.